# Montar un bak en una version diferente o como puedo bajar la version de mi sql server

Tags: sql

mi duda es que tengo un bakup de mi base de datos, pero es una version superior al gestor de base de datos al cual la tengo que montar, como podria bajar o subir la version de este bakup, y asi ya no me aparezca el error de compatibilidad?

Comment: Generalmente no se puede, pero, ¿de qué motor hablamos? ([edit] y coloca la etiqueta del motor de base de datos).

Comment: SQL SERVER  ese seria mi motor de base de datos la 2012 version 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede. Los respaldos no se pueden montar en versiones anteriores solo en versiones iguales o posteriores a la versión en la que fueron creados.

Comment: si eso estuve viendo, tuve que montar un respaldo anterior jaja, pero gracias de todas maneras.